# How to execute commands of an application in jar when the app is placed in jar?

Tags: java

I have a project built by **maven** that needs to call commands of an application(named `qvality`). So I added the app into directory `resources`(**myproject/src/main/resources/qvality**). Then I package the project with `jar`. In code, I use `this.getClass().getResource("/qvality").getPath()` to obtain the app path. However, the way is failed because of the path problem. The path is `/home/user/pipeline-reconstruction-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/qvality` using `this.getClass().getResource("/qvality").getPath()`.

So I want to know how to get the correct path of the app in jar? Or is there a better way to implement my desire?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the .jar with winrar(or other software) and insert your file. because when you export your project the file in the res folder are not export in the jar file.

Comment: This is wrong. I can make sure the app has been packed into jar file. It is only because the path is wrong obtained by `this.getClass().getResource("/qvality").getPath()`. There is a `!` in the path.

Comment: your file name qvality is in another package or in the jar ? because you should do `this.getClass().getResource("main/resources/qvality").getPath()`

Comment: Firstly, the file name qvality is in the jar. In addition, You cannot use `this.getClass().getResource("main/resources/qvality").getPath()` to get path because the compiler will warn **NullPointerException"

Comment: I did that to load an image `public static BufferedImage loadImage(String path) {
  ClassLoader loader = Textures.class.getClassLoader();
  InputStream url = loader.getResourceAsStream(path);
  BufferedImage image = null;
  try {
   image = ImageIO.read(url);
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
   System.err.println("Couln't load the texture");
   url = loader.getResourceAsStream("res/Blocks/Error.png");
   try {
    image = ImageIO.read(url);
   }
   catch(Exception e2) {
    System.err.println(e2);
   }
  }
  return image;
 }`

Comment: Yes, you can use `getResourceAsStream` to read a file. However, you cannot use `getResource` to obtain correct path to execute an app.